# Header appending for every record Rust CSV writer

Tags: rust

I want to append my records to a csv file. The problem is that my code appends the header each time. Can anyone please guide whats going wrong here?

I have defined a Row struct that contains the data i want in my csv. It has a bunch of Strings, floats etc. Please note that i have written a write_to_csv function that takes in 4 arguments, extracts the values and outputs the data to a csv. I want it to append the data to the "Arl.csv" so that i get the header for the first time and then it just appends the data every time.

```rust
use csv::Writer;
use csv::StringRecord;
use serde::Serialize;
use std::error::Error;
use std::fs::OpenOptions;
use std::io::Seek;
use std::path::Path;

// Row defines the structure of the csv file
// Please note that this a structure that has combination of String, usize, floats etc
#[derive(Debug, Serialize)]
struct Row {
    err_sigs: String,
    step: usize,
}

/// writing the results to a csv file
fn write_to_csv(
    step: usize,
    err_sigs: String,
) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let path = Path::new("arl.csv");
    let file = OpenOptions::new()
        .write(true)
        .create(true)
        .append(true)
        .open("arl.csv")?;
    let mut wtr = csv::Writer::from_writer(file);
    wtr.serialize(Row {
        err_sigs: err_sigs,
        step: step,
    })?;
    wtr.flush()?;
    Ok(())
}
```

In order to reproduce the error please use the following test-

```
fn write_to_csv_test() {
        let step = 3;
        let test_string = String::from("test1");
        

        write_to_csv(step,test_string);

        let step2=4;
        let err_signs=String::from("test2");


        write_to_csv(step2, err_signs);
    }
```

Comment: Why doesn't disabling `WriterBuilder::has_headers` work for you? https://docs.rs/csv/latest/csv/struct.WriterBuilder.html#method.has_headers

Comment: Please provide a more complete [MRE] - even after adding the missing `use` statements, there are [several errors in your code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3cf41a2a264c58b04a8bd67650e5ea54). We can't help you if you don't provide the actual code that causes your problem, so we can reproduce said problem.

Comment: good point! I did try that but then it is unable to keep a header . it only keeps data

Comment: the [docs for `serialize`](https://docs.rs/csv/latest/csv/struct.Writer.html#method.serialize) have an example that works correctly. as you will note, the two rows are written *using the same writer*; you will need to do the same.

Comment: @Finomnis hope its better now

Comment: @ricardo There are still `use` statements missing, and your test is missing a `;`. Please test your code before posting it here, otherwise you are wasting the time of the people that volunteer to help you.

Comment: @Finomnis my bad, let me update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably several solutions, but the one I could think of is to find out whether or not the file is empty, end then write the header based on that information.

Like this:

```rust
use serde::Serialize;
use std::error::Error;
use std::fs::OpenOptions;
use std::io::Seek;

// Row defines the structure of the csv file
// Please note that this a structure that has combination of String, usize, floats etc
#[derive(Debug, Serialize)]
struct Row {
    err_sigs: String,
    step: usize,
}

/// writing the results to a csv file
fn write_to_csv(step: usize, err_sigs: String) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let mut file = OpenOptions::new()
        .write(true)
        .create(true)
        .append(true)
        .open("arl.csv")?;

    let needs_headers = file.seek(std::io::SeekFrom::End(0))? == 0;

    let mut wtr = csv::WriterBuilder::new()
        .has_headers(needs_headers)
        .from_writer(file);

    wtr.serialize([Row {
        err_sigs: err_sigs.clone(),
        step: step,
    }])?;

    wtr.flush()?;
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    let step = 3;
    let test_string = String::from("test1");

    write_to_csv(step, test_string).unwrap();

    let step2 = 4;
    let err_signs = String::from("test2");

    write_to_csv(step2, err_signs).unwrap();
}
```

```
err_sigs,step
test1,3
test2,4
```